# How long can you see your own deleted answers?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

Usually, deleted answers disappear instantly, or almost instantly. Most of my answers that I have deleted, are not visible for long, maybe a few minutes at best. However, there is one answer that I deleted yesterday, which is still visible to me. Why this discrepancy/odd-behaviour? 
[image: visible delete answer]

EDIT :

Other than this, answers i deleted were *not visible* to me on the question page itself (*not through the answer link*, but simply by opening the question).

In this case, however, **it is visible to me through the *question - link* .**

[image: See the address bar]

Comment: That's strange... they're should be visible through any sort of link. (Certainly are for me.) Note that it is very different for questions when you have less than 10k rep.

Answer (score 10):

You can always see your own deleted answers, they never go away.  They will only be visible to yourself, mods, and 10k+ users.  For everyone else it disappeared right away.

You can edit the post while it's deleted and undelete it if you want (since it was deleted by you, and not a mod).

Comment: They're just hard to find, since you'll have no reference to them.

Comment: Potentially, yes.  They won't show up in your list of posts on your profile, or in any search engines, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Are you saying that in a discussion in which I deleted an answer, that answer will always display for me when I visit the question, or that I will only see the answer when I reference directly via a [share](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161195/150038) link?

Comment: @palswim The former.

Answer (score 7):

You can always see your own deleted answers, no matter how long it has been. However, they will not show up in your posts list after a time; that list could be cached to some degree, so you might see a deleted answer in your answer list for a few minutes. But if you keep the URL, you can *always* go back and view the post.