# Can't see my own deleted answer anymore after question is moderator-deleted

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I recently asked for a moderator to delete [a question that I asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229610/undelete-old-question-about-recommended-python-blogs), and it was deleted. On this question, I had also given my own ***answer***, which I deleted myself before I flagged the question to be deleted. ***Immediately after*** I deleted my answer, I could still see it in deleted form on the question.

That's all fine. ***However***, when I look at the question ***after*** it has been deleted by a moderator, ***I can no longer see the answer that I deleted***. I only see the deleted answer of one of the moderators. I would expect to see both deleted answers, not just one:

[image]

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161195/163250), users can see their own deleted answers:

> You can always see your own deleted answers, they never go away. They will only be visible to yourself, mods, and 10k+ users.

And according to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108078/163250),

> there is no reputation limit to see your own deleted answers

**So is this a bug if I can't see my own deleted answer anymore?** Usually, when I delete my own answer, I can still see it after it has been deleted, immediately. I'm not aware of any sort of time-limit before I can see my own deleted answers. And of course, answers are soft-deleted...[most of the time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195996/163250):

> Occasionally hard deletions are made by the dev team, however this is usually only 1 revision removed because it contained sensitive information (passwords etc.).

But I don't remember my answer containing any sort of sensitive information (feel free to correct me if I'm wrong).

## Reproducibility

I'm not sure if this is reproducible. I'm not sure how to go about reproducing it, other than asking another question and then flagging a moderator to delete it again. So just to be clear, here are the sequence of events that did happen, if anyone wants to try to reproduce:

1. Post a question and answer it at the same time (in one step, not two separate steps).
2. Have a moderator post an answer.
3. Delete your own answer.
4. Have the moderator delete the whole question.

Comment: I have no idea why you can't see your own deleted answer, if you still have a link to the question.  Can you see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229611/102937)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey that link shows me the question and ***your answer***, but that's the only answer I see still, I still don't see my own deleted answer. Do you see 2 deleted answers?

Comment: Well, I think that's a bug then.  Your question was moderator-deleted at your request.  The answer just goes along for the ride.  Seems like it is not recognizing ownership of your answer.

Comment: FYI - I can see your answer, so if you can't see it, I'd concur that this is a bug

Comment: Heh. Edge case - given that you are both the asker of the question and the poster of an answer on it... Looking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, this was a real edge case.

We were filtering out some answers even when the answer OP was the current user.

Fixed in the next build (rev 2014.4.16.1551, meta rev 2014.4.16.2164).

Comment: I change my mind, I don't want to see my answer anymore. j/k, LOL! Thanks! `#EpicWin`.